# Move iPad Screenshots to an album

Tags: ios, ipad, automator, screen-capture

I have an iPad Pro, and I'm wondering if there is a way to auto save a screenshot from my iPad to an album name e.g.: iPad Pro

[image: iPads]

Is there an automated way in iOS that I can do that for only my iPad?

---

I found a way to do that in [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) but they detect any screenshot from all my iOS devices, even the one I took from my iPhone, and because of that it messed up the automation.

[image: IFTTT]

Please let me know if there is another way to do this in a fully automatic manner.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, one way to accomplish this is to use the **Shortcuts** app by **Apple**, available on the **App Store** for **iOS** devices.

Here is the [App Store Preview link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/shortcuts/id915249334?mt=8) for **Shortcuts**.

After installing the **Shortcuts** app, do the following:

1. Open: **Shortcuts**
2. Tap: **Create Shortcut**
3. Scroll down to **Photos & Videos** and tap: **Get Latest Screenshots**
4. Scroll back down to **Photos & Videos** and tap: **Save to Photo Album**
5. On the **Save to Photo Album** shortcut, tap **Camera Roll** and on the **Album** sheet select e.g.: **iPad Pro**
6. At the top of the **Untitled Shortcut** screen tap the **Settings** icon (the double switch).

From here, you can give it a name and set the various controls, tapping **Done** when finished.

The following is an image of the sample shortcut I created which, as initially set up, saves the latest screenshot to the e.g. **iPad Pro** album.

[image: Shortcut workflow]

The following image shows the result of running the shortcut pictured in the image above, and as you can see the last screenshot was of the shortcut I created.

[image: Shortcut workflow with result]

<sub>Obviously the screenshots were taken on my iPhone and are for demonstration purposes only, you'd install the Snapshots app on your iPad and use it there. You can also install and use it on your iPhone but its independent of your iPad install and not directly linked.</sub>

Comment: I did that as u suggested but now all my screenshots still not go there to iPad Pro folder unless I pressed play. Can I make all my screenshots go to my iPad pro automatically?

Comment: Am I missing some things here ?

Comment: @kyo, Yes, you need to click the run button and is in part why I started my answer with "As an alternative".

Comment: I see. Let me know if u know how to auto move all screenshots to specific folder  right after taking them